# Is Hamiltonian cycle problem on graphs with out-degree at most 3 NP hard?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, np-complete, np-hard, hamiltonian-circuit

I am trying to show a different form of Hamiltonian cycle problem is NP Hard. The problem is as follows.

> We have a directed graph and each node can have at most 3 outgoing edges. Determine if this graph has a Hamiltonian cycle.

Is this problem NP hard?

I just need to find a problem to reduce to my problem but could achieve to find none.

3SAT looks friendly to me as it has 3-termed clauses but no more I progressed.

Comment: Try reduction from the usual Hamiltonian cycle problem.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus yeah but I do not want answer but just a hint to go on

Comment: I already gave you a hint. Try a reduction from Hamiltonian cycle. I don't know if the hint works, but it seems like a good thing to try.

Comment: Hint: When reducing from Hamiltonian Cycle as suggested by @YuvalFilmus, you can add many more "helping" vertices to each original vertex, provided you can figure out a way to let them all be visited when the original vertex is.

Comment: Hint #2: Draw a small example graph on paper, using unfilled circles for the vertices.  This hopefully gives you an idea that... won't work just yet, because some HCs in the original graph might leave vertices in the constructed graph unvisited.  But perhaps this can be dealt with using a few more helpers...

Comment: If you has figured out this problem, please write an answer (yes, you can answer your own question).